# Could someone please identify this garnish?

Tags: garnish

There are zoomed in images lower down on the page:

https://drizzleanddip.com/2013/02/01/jamie-olivers-fennel-and-radish-salad/

[image]

I'm just in love with how this looks, I'm thinking it would be gorgeous over potatoes!

Comment: If you’re just going for looks, dill looks similar, as does asparagus (if you let it grow past where it’s commercially picked)

Comment: you mean beside the fennel and radish from the "Fennel And Radish Salad"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its fennel leaves/fronds - and often when you're buying whole fennel bulbs, they're attached, or sometimes they're sold separately - south indian cooking has the fronds but we don't generally eat the bulbs traditionally.

Comment: … and if the bulbs come with the fronds, they are a good indicator of freshness.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek I had no idea, I've never seen them before! There's a south Indian market in my city that I've been meaning to visit, now I have another reason! Do the fronds have some fennel flavor. or just a green flavor?

Comment: Its a very delicate flavour - I'd almost say faintly like fennel (naturally) and a little floral.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek this just makes my day, thank you so much!

Comment: Depending on where you live you might not need to take a field strip to a specialty market; my regular supermarket starts stocking fresh fennel when it's in season, which should be now in most of the Northern hemisphere (fall/winter.) Also the white stuff in that photo is actually the fennel bulb, shaved or mandolined.

Comment: Heck, if you live in the NW American/Canadian coast, you can find fennel growing wild and/or as a decorative plant.